# how to remove placeholder in URL

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can anyone give me a clue how to solve this?

I've got, for example, this URL: `http://www.someweb.cz/api/1.0/controller/method/{0}`

And I want to remove `{0}` from it. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: `string.Format("whatever url you get", <whatever you want to replace with>)`

Comment: You need give more details. Is the string you want to replace *literally* "{0}" or is that an example? Does it always occur only once at the very end of a string?

Comment: Are you sure the API does not expect some kind of parameter there?

Comment: `"http://www.someweb.cz/api/1.0/controller/method/{0}".Replace("{0}", "");`. Next.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`string.Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_String_Format_System_String_System_Object___) or [`string.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.7.1) and use an empty string:

```
var url = "http://www.someweb.cz/api/1.0/controller/method/{0}";
var replaceWith = ""; //empty string

var fixedUrl1 = string.Format(url, replaceWith);
var fixedUrl2 = url.Replace("{0}", replaceWith);
```